# Set the user's profile on creation

Tags: python, django

I have a user profile model (one to one with `User`) that looks like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    facebook_id = CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    google_id = CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email

# creates a corresponding profile for the newly created user
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def user_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

and I would like to set the user's profile when I create a new user, so something like this:

```
    user = User(
        first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
        last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
        username=validated_data['username'])

    user.profile['facebook_id'] = social_id
```

But this doesn't seem to work. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: "this doesn't seem to work" is not the most helpful error description.

Comment: Sorry. I get an error saying `User does not have a profile`. And when I tried to save the user before setting the profile I got an error saying `'Profile' object does not support item assignment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an unsaved instance of the user Model, so the `post_save` signal is not sent. Use:

```
user = User.objects.create(
    first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
    last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
    username=validated_data['username']
)
```

or:

```
user = User(
    first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
    last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
    username=validated_data['username'])
user.save()
```

After creating the User object, the signal handler will create the profile, so you can set the attribute:

```
user.profile.facebook_id = social_id
user.profile.save()
```

Comment: How do I set the `facebook_id` after this?

Comment: 'Profile' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Yeah, right, its a model, so you use `.attribute` not `['attribute']`. Updated the answer

Comment: .attribute is what raises the error. Both ways dont work

Comment: Are you importing CharField from models?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203669/discussion-between-daniel-hepper-and-ninesalt).